# Display product custom field as order item meta on WooCommerce admin order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, admin

I have created my woocommerce products (fruits and vegetables) with a bunch of custom meta data I can correctly input and display them on my website. One of this data is the unit (ie kilos, box of 6, etc.).

On the **Admin order page**, I'd like to display this "unit" field right below the name of the products (ex : Strawberry - kilo / Eggs - box of 6, etc.).

I have tried the following code and have the following result (see screenshot) :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'unit_before_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
function unit_before_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $_product ){
        if( $unit = $_product->get_meta('unite') ) {
        echo '<p>'.$unit.'</p>';}
}
```

And here is the result :
[Screemshot single order page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTDEi.jpg)
=> The meta field 'unit' is correctly displayedunder each product, but for some reason it breaks the page and I have a critical error mesage (highlited in red) at the bottom of the page.

I have read a lot of posts here about different way to catch and display (return, print...) my meta data, but I always end up having this critical error.

Could someone help me understand what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target order "line" items only and admin to avoid errors, as follow:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'unit_before_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
function unit_before_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $product ){
    // Only "line" items and backend order pages
    if( ! ( is_admin() && $item->is_type('line_item') ) ) return;

    $unit = $product->get_meta('unite');
    if( ! empty($unit) ) {
        echo '<p>'.$unit.'</p>';
    }
}
```

It should better work now without errors.